# Rank of $A^T$ is $5$.Yes/No

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the following statements true or false?

$1.$ Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4 $ real matrix such that $A^3=I$. Then $1$  necessarily  is  an eigenvalue of  $A.$

$2.$ Let $A$ be a $5 \times 8$ real matrix such that $\operatorname{Nullity}\left(A^TA\right)=3$. Then $\operatorname{Rank}\left(A^T\right)=5$

**My attempt**: I think statement $1$ is true because $x^3=1\implies x^3-1=0 \implies (x-1)(x^2 +x+1)\implies x=1 $ is an eigenvalue of $A.$

Statement $2$ is also true because  $A^TA$ is an $8 \times 8$ matrix.
$$\operatorname{Nullity}\left(A^TA\right)=3 \implies\operatorname{Rank}\left(A^TA\right)=5.$$

$$\operatorname{Rank} \left(A^TA\right) = \min \left\{\operatorname{Rank}(A), \text{Rank}\left(A^T\right)\right\} =5.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$B=\begin{pmatrix}-{1\over 2} & \phantom{-}{3\over 4}\\
-1 &- {1\over 2}\end{pmatrix} $$ The characteristic polynomial of $B$ is equal $x^2+x+1.$ Therefore $B^2+B+I=0.$ Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}  B & 
0 \\ 0& B \end{pmatrix}$$ Then $A^2+A+I=0,$ which implies $A^3=I.$ The number $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A.$

Concerning $2,$ the assumption implies $\dim \ker A=3.$ Therefore the rank of $A$ is equal $5.$ So is the rank of $A^T.$